# Github running pull request build pipeline despite pull request validation being disabled from Azure pipeline

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

I have a duplicate pipeline let us call is A and B. I have disabled pull request validation for the pipeline B, however despite the change when a pull request is raised A and B still both run, and what is worrying is that because automation execution has been disabled for pipeline B, it holds up the pull request and becomes a blocker. The way around is to manually run pileine B.

I cannot seem to remove pipeline B from the validation checks for pull requests. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I have two same pipelines in Azure DevOps. "EnablePR-A" and "DisablePR-B".

The trigger setting is as below:

[image]

[image]

When a PR is made in GitHub repo, A is triggered.

[image]

To check the trigger setting in your pipeline:

[image]

Also, you could check how your pipeline is being triggered:

[image]

[image]